# Amazon thermostat setup with heat pump (w/e and Rc jumper questions)

Tags: hvac, thermostat

So I'm in process on installing my Amazon thermostat, which had seemed straightforward until, while hooking up the O/B wiring, I noticed the little warning tag on the new tstat saying not to hook up the W with the air pump.

Problem is that the old thermostat has both hooked up and it seemed like it worked, although it seemed like the heat pump was always running, which I attributed to the cold and bad insulation.  The people I bought it from did an idiot's flip, which is to say that they only seemed to hire idiots to work on it.

Tried to upload the pic (too big for the post) of the old setup (Pro1 Model T721)which has two Rs jumpered with red going in and a W/E and W2 jumpered together with a white wire going into w/e.

On the new tstat there's no W/E, but there's a W, an E and a W2.

Will upload the pics as I can get them shrunk down size wise to make the forum happy.

So if I'm not hooking up the W wire, what do I do with it?  Tape it off and tuck it away?

Amazon on top

Pro1 on bottom with jumpers still in place

https://imgur.com/gallery/9tTmDC3

Comment: Try uploading the picture to [imgur](https://imgur.com) then posting a link to it here